# How to identify subrequests in Nginx log files

Tags: nginx, logging

When using `log_subrequest on` in Nginx, how can I identify log lines that are subrequests?

Apache has the variable `IS_SUBREQ` but Nginx does not seem to have an equivalent.

I am using the `slice` module and processing my logs with [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack) and need to separate the log lines for main requests from log lines for subrequests.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

There is a way, but not without a little programming involved.

- Remove query string part from `$request_uri`
- URI-unescape the result
- Add the `$query_string`, if any
- Add the `$query_string` to `$uri`
- Compare the enhanced `$uri` with the modified `$request_uri`, if they are not equal to each other, you just discovered a subrequest.

## Long Answer

Currently, there seems to be no way to distinguish between user-interacted requests and subrequests with a simple **variable** like in Apache. Something like `$is_subreq` simply **isn't available**. (nginx dev team, anyone?)

At the moment I am programming a htaccess plugin for nginx, where I needed to find a way to make sure the current request is the original one. This can be achieved by **comparing `$uri` with `$request_uri`**, and if they differ, the request is a follow-up.

But **be careful**, if you boldly compare the variables, you will fail:
`$uri` lacks its `$query_string` and is URL-decoded, while `$request_uri` is left untouched (still encoded), with its query string attached.

Here is a code snipped from my actual project (htaccess implementation in Lua), where you can see how I have done it:

```lua
local org_request_uri = ngx.var.request_uri
-- The original requested URI including query string.
-- Make sure uri doesn't end on '?', as request_uri will never match that.
org_request_uri_path = org_request_uri:match('^[^%?]+')
if org_request_uri:len() > org_request_uri_path:len() then
    org_request_uri = ngx.unescape_uri(org_request_uri_path)..
        org_request_uri:sub(org_request_uri_path:len()+1)
else
    org_request_uri = ngx.unescape_uri(org_request_uri_path)
end

local request_uri = ngx.var.uri -- The actual requested URI including query string
if ngx.var.query_string then
    request_uri = request_uri..'?'..ngx.var.query_string
end
```